# Logout when print Qweb report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, logout

How can I close the odoo session after printing a qweb report?

What I want is to close session after clicking Sample Report

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <odoo>

  <record id="paperformat_euro_landscape" 
   model="report.paperformat"> 
   <field name="name">European A4 Landscape</field> 
   <field name="default" eval="True" /> 
   <field name="format">A4</field> 
   <field name="page_height">0</field> 
   <field name="page_width">0</field> 
   <field name="orientation">Landscape</field> 
   <field name="margin_top">35</field> 
   <field name="margin_bottom">15</field> 
   <field name="margin_left">7</field> 
   <field name="margin_right">7</field> 
   <field name="header_line" eval="False" /> 
   <field name="header_spacing">35</field> 
   <field name="dpi">90</field> 
 </record> 

 <report id="action_mantto_task_report" 
  string="Sample Report" 
  model="rep.oper" 
  report_type="qweb-pdf" 
  name="repop_report.report_repop_task_template"
  paperformat="paperformat_euro_landscape" 
  /> 

</template> 
</odoo>
```

Comment: Hi, You want to do that for all reports or just for one.

Comment: Hi @KararaMohamed, just for  one.